# Loop request and extract data from Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-requests

I'm trying to extract data from an Excel file (like this one) and then post request to url using a payload like this one:

```
session.post(url, proxies =proxy, data=json.dumps({
    'Password': "password",
    'Username': "username"
    })
```

So I want to send python into a loop until it finishes logging all the accounts with their respective proxy.

[image]

Edit:How do i define each data of it so i can use in my post request? I need it to post request on loop till all the accounts are done
Basically need the data to be stored in a variable then goes to next line after done executing the request

Answer (score 0):

To open and read an **excel file**, use **openpyxl** and iterate through the data rows.

Try this code:

```
###### create test file ######

from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i,hdr in enumerate(['Account','Password','Proxy']):
   ws.cell(1,i+1).value = hdr
   
for i in range(5):
   ws.cell(i+2,1).value = 'User' + str(i+1)
   ws.cell(i+2,2).value = 'Pwd' + str(i+1)
   ws.cell(i+2,3).value = ((str(i+1)*3+'.')*3)[0:-1] + ':8080'

wb.save(r'test.xlsx') 

######### main script #########

from openpyxl import load_workbook

urls = [
"https://www.111.com",
"https://www.222.com",
"https://www.333.com"
]

def postdata(user,pwd,proxy,url):
   print('PostData > ',user,pwd,proxy,url)
#   session.post(url, proxies =proxy, data=json.dumps({
#    'Password': pwd,
#    'Username': user
#    })

# load excel data
prxlst = []
wb = load_workbook(r'test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active  # first worksheet
for i in range(1,ws.max_row):  # each row
   prxlst.append((ws.cell(i+1,1).value,ws.cell(i+1,2).value,ws.cell(i+1,3).value))
wb.close()

# run data post    
for prx in prxlst:  # each proxy
    for url in urls:  # each url
       postdata(prx[0],prx[1],prx[2],url)
```

Output

```
PostData >  User1 Pwd1 111.111.111:8080 https://www.111.com
PostData >  User1 Pwd1 111.111.111:8080 https://www.222.com
PostData >  User1 Pwd1 111.111.111:8080 https://www.333.com
PostData >  User2 Pwd2 222.222.222:8080 https://www.111.com
PostData >  User2 Pwd2 222.222.222:8080 https://www.222.com
PostData >  User2 Pwd2 222.222.222:8080 https://www.333.com
.......
```

I don't have enough information about the post process to add that in the code.

Comment: How do i define each data of it so i can use in my post request? I need it to post request on loop till all the accounts are done

Comment: `postdata` function added. Put your posting logic there. For the data, fill in the excel file and remove the `create test file` section in the code.

Comment: How do I go back to `def postdata(user,pwd,proxy):` or anything to loop? I mean I want it to go back to original state after all the requests have been executed then head for 2nd row then post data  on loop till all rows done?

Comment: So you have multiple URLs and you want to run all proxies for each URL?

Comment: I have multiple URLs to go through but only one account and proxy at a time. After first account (e.g. User1 Pwd1 111.111.111.8080) done going through the whole request session, I want to summon up User2 and so on

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I wanted to send a group of requests with one account/proxy and then repeat the same requests with different account/proxy